# Can I update Windows ClientIdentities after cluster creation?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I currently have something like this in my cluseterConfig.json file.

```
"ClientIdentities": [
                {
                    "Identity": "{My Domain}\\{My Security Group}",
                    "IsAdmin": true
                }
            ]
```

My questions are:

1. My cluster is stood up and running.  Can I add a second security group to this cluster while running?  I've search through the powershell commands and didn't see one that matched this but I may have missed it?
2. If I can't do this while the cluster is running do I need delete the cluster and recreate?  If I do need to recreate I'm zeroing in on the word ClientIdentitie**s**.  I'm assuming I can have multiple identities and my config should look something like

   ClientIdentities": [{

   ```
                   "Identity": "{My Domain}\\{My Security Group}",
                   "IsAdmin": true
               },

               {
                   "Identity": "{My Domain}\\{My Second Security Group}",
                   "IsAdmin": false
               } 
           ]
   ```

Thanks, 
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to update ClientIdentities once the cluster is up using a configuration upgrade.

1. Create a new JSON file with the added client identities.
2. Modify the clusterConfigurationVersion in the JSON config.
3. Run Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade -ClusterConfigPath "Path to new JSON"

Comment: Will mark as answer as soon as I verify.  We are knee deep in getting the application ready for deployment so I'm sorry its taking me a few to get this updated.  Thank you :)